# How to hide a folder from another developer in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to create a repository in GitLab for programming competition (for example, python). Each competitor/student needs to create a branch and working on this personal branch. And I plan to test it automatically by using CI in GitLab. I create a `test` folder to contain all the test cases.

I think competitors can create a personal branch like this:

```sh
$ git branch John.Doe
$ git checkout John.Doe
$ git push origin John.Doe
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/John.Doe John.Doe
```

**How do I hide this `test` from the competitors? How do I protect my master branch?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Git to hide branches from others who have read access to the repository.  Even if you use hidden refs (which are not available in most hosting solutions), it's possible to extract information about other commits.

If you need to store private data, you should use a separate, private repository.  Alternately, if this is only for CI, you can store your data encrypted in the repository and use a secret in the CI system to decrypt it only for CI purposes.  GitHub [describes how to do this](https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#creating-and-using-secrets-encrypted-variables) using `gpg` for GitHub Actions; you can follow similar steps for GitLab.

Comment: Aye, and you can even set different push and pull upstreams and add custom remotes to keep things in sync. Git is very powerful!